# Using Python elastisearch_dsl with nested objects

Tags: python, elasticsearch-dsl

I want to try and use elasticsearch_dsl with python for the following

```
import elasticsearch

es_server = 'my_server_name'
es_port = '9200'
es_index_name = 'my_index_name'
es_connection = Elasticsearch([{'host': es_server, 'port': es_port}])

es_query = '{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"data.party.fullName":"john do"}}],"must_not":[],"should":[]}},"from":0,"size":1,"sort":[],"facets":{}}'
my_results = es_connection.search(index=es_index_name, body=es_query)
print  my_results

es_query ='{"query": {"nested" : {"filter" : {"term" : {"party.phoneList.phoneFullNumber" : "4081234567"}},"path" : "party.phoneList"}},"from" :0,"size" : 1}';
my_results = es_connection.search(index=es_index_name, body=es_query)
print  my_results
```

I am able to get the 1st query but am not sure on the second one

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search, Q

client = Elasticsearch('my_server:9200')
s = Search(using=client, index = "my_index").query("term",fullName="john do ")
response = s.execute()
print response
```

Not sure how to do the query using DSL for the nested object party.phoneList.phoneFullNumber

New to ES and hence could not figure out how to do the nested objects.
I looked at  https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/issues/28 and could not quite figure out.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `__` instead of `.` to get around python's limitations and the `nested` query:

```
s = Search(using=client, index = "my_index")
s = s.query("nested",
    path="party.phoneList",
    query=Q("term", party__phoneList__phoneFullNumber="4081234567")
)
```